# trying to write an INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS with multiple WHEN THEN

Tags: insert, case, multiple-columns, case-when, not-exists

I'm trying to write an `INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS` with multiple `WHEN THEN`

```
INSERT INTO [coll18_tesutest].[PERMIL_STATUSES] (PERMIL_STATUSES.POS, PER_MILITARY_ID, 
PERMIL_MIL_STATUS, PERMIL_BRANCH, PERMIL_STATUS_START_DATE, 
PERMIL_STATUS_END_DATE,PERMIL_PRIMARY_FLAG)

     SELECT TOP 10 
         MILITARY_ASSOC.POS, MILITARY_ASSOC.ID, MILITARY_STATUSES, 
         MILITARY_BRANCHES, MILITARY_START_DATES, MILITARY_END_DATES
     FROM 
         MILITARY_ASSOC 
     JOIN 
         STPR_STATUSES ON SUBSTRING(STPR_STATUSES.STUDENT_PROGRAMS_ID, 1, 7) = (MILITARY_ASSOC.ID) 
     WHERE 
         STPR_STATUSES.POS = 1 
         AND STPR_STATUS = 'A'  
         AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 10 *
                             (CASE MILITARY_STATUS
                                 WHEN 'AAIR' OR 'AANG' OR 'AARMY' OR 'ACG' OR 'AMAR' OR 'ANAVY' OR 'ANG'
                                    THEN 'ACT'
                                 WHEN 'DODAF' OR 'DODAG' OR 'DODAR' OR 'DODCG' OR 'DODMA' OR 'DODNA' OR 'DODNG' 
                                    THEN 'DOD'
                                 WHEN 'FAMAF' OR 'FAMAG' OR 'FAMAR' OR 'FAMCG' OR 'FAMMA' OR 'FAMNA' OR 'FAMNG' 
                                    THEN 'DEP'
                                 WHEN 'RAIR' OR 'RARMY' OR 'RCG' OR 'RMAR' OR 'RNAVY' OR 'RNG' 
                                    THEN 'RES'
                                 WHEN 'VAIR' OR 'VANG' OR 'VARM' OR 'VCG' OR 'VMAR' OR 'VNAVY' OR 'VNG'
                                    THEN 'HON'
                                 ELSE NULL
                              END) AS PERMIL_MIL_STATUS,
(CASE MILITARY_STATUSES
WHEN 'AAIR' OR 'DODAF' OR 'FAMAF' OR 'RAIR' OR 'VAIR'
THEN 'AF'
WHEN 'AANG' OR 'DODAG' OR 'FAMAG' OR 'VANG'
THEN 'ANG'
WHEN 'AARMY' OR 'DODAR' OR 'FAMAR' OR 'RARMY' OR 'VARM'
THEN 'ARMY' 
WHEN 'ACG' OR 'DODCG' OR 'FAMCG' OR 'RCG' OR 'VCG' 
THEN 'CG'
WHEN 'AMAR' OR 'DODMA' OR 'FAMMA' OR 'RMAR' OR 'VMAR' 
THEN 'M'
WHEN 'ANAVY' OR 'DODNA' OR 'FAMNA' OR 'RNAVY' OR 'VNAVY'
THEN 'NAVY'
WHEN 'ANG' OR 'DODNG' OR 'FAMNG' OR 'RNG' OR 'VNG'  
THEN 'NG'
ELSE NULL 
END) AS PERMIL_BRANCH 
FROM PERMIL_STATUSES
WHERE PER_MILITARY_ID=MILITARY_ASSOC.ID
AND PERMIL_STATUSES.POS=1
AND PERMIL_PRIMARY_FLAG='YES');


----------
```

Comment: What is your question. Please elaborate your trials etc.

Comment: It doesn't work.  It complains about the ( around the first CASE